# Gradle plugin 'com.android.library' does not search in custom maven repositories

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here is how my application module 'app' build gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/' }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile 'com.testpackage.networking:networking:1.0.3'
}
```

and it works just fine. I'm trying to use same dependency in my library module named 'librarymodule'. Here is how its build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/'
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3'
    compile 'com.testpackage.networking:networking:1.0.3'
}
```

The only difference is gradle plugin 'com.android.library' used here vs 'com.android.application' used in 'app' module.

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.testpackage.networking:networking:1.0.3.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/testpackage/networking/networking/1.0.3/networking-1.0.3.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/testpackage/networking/networking/1.0.3/networking-1.0.3.jar
>            file:/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/testpackage/networking/networking/1.0.3/networking-1.0.3.pom
>            file:/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/testpackage/networking/networking/1.0.3/networking-1.0.3.jar
>            file:/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/testpackage/networking/networking/1.0.3/networking-1.0.3.pom
>            file:/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/testpackage/networking/networking/1.0.3/networking-1.0.3.jar
>        Required by:
>            LibrariesApplication:app:unspecified > LibrariesApplication:librarymodule:unspecified

So, for some reason there is no *http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/com/testpackage/networking/networking/1.0.3/networking-1.0.3.pom* under *Searched in the following locations* list.

It's not only my repository problems. I can for example use

```
maven { url 'https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/' }
```

repository with dependency

```
compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.1'
```

and still getting similar error

Does anyone knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit strange but adding custom repository to 'allprojects' of root build.gradle actually worked!

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'http://localhost:8080/repository/internal/'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This allowed me to resolve a dependency of a jar in one maven repo by looking in another

Answer (score -3):

If you don't want to put the maven credentials in the project file (and you shouldn't), create a "gradle.properties" file in your home directory and put the maven credentials in that file, like:

```
mavenUser=myUser
mavenPassword=myPassword
```

Then, in your build.gradle file, use as follows:

```
maven {
    credentials {
        username mavenUser
        password mavenPassword
    }
    url http://my.maven.url
}
```